# How is D3 computing the displayed date values on this chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm studying the code in this example:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/978f6c03c9aab8af8594#data.tsv

```
var formatPercent = d3.format("+.0%"),
    formatChange = function(x) { return formatPercent(x - 1); },
    parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.log()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickSize(-width, 0)
    .tickFormat(formatChange);

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.ratio); });

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.ratio); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var gX = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

var gY = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y");

gY.append("text")
    .attr("class", "axis-title")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .text("Change in Price");

d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // Compute price relative to base value (hypothetical purchase price).
  var baseValue = +data[0].close;
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.ratio = d.close / baseValue;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.ratio; }));

  area.y0(y(1));

  // Use a second linear scale for ticks.
  yAxis.tickValues(d3.scale.linear()
      .domain(y.domain())
      .ticks(20));

  gX.call(xAxis);

  gY.call(yAxis)
    .selectAll(".tick")
      .classed("tick--one", function(d) { return Math.abs(d - 1) < 1e-6; });

  var defs = svg.append("defs");

  defs.append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip-above")
    .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", y(1));

  defs.append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip-below")
    .append("rect")
      .attr("y", y(1))
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height - y(1));

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip-above)")
      .attr("class", "area area--above")
      .attr("d", area);

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip-below)")
      .attr("class", "area area--below")
      .attr("d", area);

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
});
```

How does D3 compute the displayed time format in the x-axis?

I see this line of the code:

```
parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;
```

but how does this result in the dates over a few years being displayed as "April" "2009" etc? Is this an automatic setting in D3? Does it relate to tick mark spacing? I'm not sure where the x-axis settings are being made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you're quoting is irrelevant to how D3 outputs its dates: it is the function that transforms the dates in the CSV (11-Feb-08 for example) into something usable.

The x axis scale is defined as a [time scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales) by `var x = d3.time.scale` and the format is given by the default value in [`scale.tickFormat`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#tickFormat)

> Returns a time format function suitable for displaying a tick value.
> You don't have to use the scale's built-in tick format, but it
> automatically computes the appropriate display based on the input
> date.
>
> The following time formats are considered:
>
> - %Y - for year boundaries, such as "2011".
> - %B - for month boundaries, such as "February".
> - %b %d - for week
>   boundaries, such as "Feb 06".
> - %a %d - for day boundaries, such as "Mon 07".
> - %I %p - for hour boundaries, such as "01 AM".
> - %I:%M - for minute
>   boundaries, such as "01:23".
> - :%S - for second boundaries, such as ":45".
> - .%L - milliseconds for all other times, such as ".012".

Basically, D3's magic at work